# Make print come after `if` in python

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm making a quiz and when I make an `if` statement in python to put a question I have to put the print before it(which I'm using at answers). So my question is how to make it come after without stopping the `if` statement. Any ideas appreciated. Sorry if its hard to know what I'm trying to say I'm a little new to python.

Comment: Can you add your code please? :)

Comment: Would suggest adding some code and elaborating on what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
answer = input ('Who was the last king of Rome? ') #use raw_input for python2.x
if answer == 'Tarquinius': print ('correct')
else: print ('incorrect')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'asdf' if 1 == 2 else 'fdsa'
```

Or if you don't get that this does, try this:

`print "ok..nice" if raw_input("how are you ") == "ok" else "well, that's too bad"`

Apparently people don't know the new inline `if` syntax, and think i'm trolling.

This should all be written in 1 line and does not require splitting.

Comment: No code formatting? No colons? Not even a newline? For a user of over 1.5k rep, I'm disappointed. You could at least take more than 5 seconds to try to help out a fellow programmer.

Comment: @Josh have you tried the line of code before giving me thumbs down?

Comment: I apologize for the rash comment and down vote, I couldn't recognize your syntax without the code formatting. Perhaps next time you'll take another two seconds to indent and add a short explanation

Comment: yes, i have learned my lesson :)